# Why cant I get 400X800 resolution in my AVD

Tags: resolution, screen-resolution, android-virtual-device

I am using Eclipse and if my AVD is set at WVGA800 The highest resolution I see is 320X533 with the title bar gone. If my AVD is set at WVGA854 The highest resolution I see is 320X568 with the title bar gone. 
The Emulator is set for Android 2.2 API 8 and I am using XPSP3

Why cant I get 400X800 resolution?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" It starts the emulator in a lower screen resolution. by changing the minSdkVersion to 8 I was able to get the full screen resolution on my emulator.